# Show every number up to a certain number given in a variable

Tags: php, date

I have a bit of a problem, I'm trying to make a calendar which I can then change the color of each box depending on the result from the database. at the moment my code gives me how many days there are in the year. is there a way which I can make say for instance 30 boxed with each number ascending to 30, in a way which will let me select a certain number of a box later on and make that a certain color.

```
  <?php
$number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 2, 2003); 
?>
```

I have tried ways I use on fetching information from rows in databases which obviously will not work.
Kind Regards
Jack

Comment: please, publish your tries, we will enhance your solution. Which specific problem did you met?

Comment: For the title: using [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php), like [this](https://eval.in/604668).

Comment: it will only show me the row as 31. I need to know how I can get it to repeat from by adding a number until it gets to 30 and showing every single number.  1,2,3,4,5,etc.

Comment: That's very helpful @FirstOne how can I make each number have its own box and make the each box accessible. if I wanted to remove 5 by making a certain variable 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hoped, with all sincerity, that we are in sync here. One can presume he understands what you meant but then it may not be that precise. Anyways, you can `loop` through the variable `$number` with a `for(){}` loop and then create your boxes (perhaps an HTML `<div>` Element) with unique `css classes` to help you `style`it as you wish. Here's what is assumed to be one probable idea:

```
    <?php
        $number     = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 2, 2003);

        // LOOP THROUGH THE NUMBER OF MONTHS USING FOR-LOOP AND CREATE
        // THE BOXES THAT YOU DESIRE (WITH CSS-CLASSES, THOUGH)
        $calBoxes   = "";
        for($cue=1; $cue<=$number; $cue++){
            $fmtDay    = date("D", strtotime("2003-2-{$cue}"));
            $calBoxes .= "<div class='date-box date-box-{$cue}'>" . PHP_EOL;
            $calBoxes .= "<span class='date-number date-number-{$cue}'>{$fmtDay}</span>" . PHP_EOL;
            $calBoxes .= "<span class='weekday weekday-{$cue} weekday-" . strtolower($fmtDay) . "'>{$cue}</span>" . PHP_EOL;
            $calBoxes .= "</div>" . PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo $calBoxes; //<== DIRECTLY OUTPUTS THE DATA

        // JUST FOR TESTING PURPOSES; YOU MAY SIMPLY DO A var_dump();
        // var_dump($calBoxes);
        // PRODUCES...          
        <div class='date-box date-box-1'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-1'>Sat</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-1 weekday-sat'>1</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-2'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-2'>Sun</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-2 weekday-sun'>2</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-3'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-3'>Mon</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-3 weekday-mon'>3</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-4'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-4'>Tue</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-4 weekday-tue'>4</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-5'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-5'>Wed</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-5 weekday-wed'>5</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-6'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-6'>Thu</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-6 weekday-thu'>6</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-7'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-7'>Fri</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-7 weekday-fri'>7</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-8'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-8'>Sat</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-8 weekday-sat'>8</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-9'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-9'>Sun</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-9 weekday-sun'>9</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-10'>
        <span class='date-number date-number-10'>Mon</span>
        <span class='weekday weekday-10 weekday-mon'>10</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-11'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-11'>Tue</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-11 weekday-tue'>11</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-12'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-12'>Wed</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-12 weekday-wed'>12</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-13'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-13'>Thu</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-13 weekday-thu'>13</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-14'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-14'>Fri</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-14 weekday-fri'>14</span>
        </div>
        <div class='date-box date-box-15'>
            <span class='date-number date-number-15'>Sat</span>
            <span class='weekday weekday-15 weekday-sat'>15</span>
        </div>...
```

Hope this gives you (at least) a little clue...

Cheers ;-)

Comment: thanks that's exactly what I needed. I understand how it works now

Comment: @jwdbjbebefin    ;-)   Since it's a Calendar, you may need the Days like Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu... The Post was updated to take that into consideration. Cheers again ;-)

Comment: Thanks again appreciate your kindness.

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you, at the top of the results it says ' string(4862) " ' how would i get rid of that.

Comment: @jwdbjbebefin    The reason is because you are not `echo`ing the result. You should remove the `var_dump($calBoxes)` and replace it with `echo $calBoxes;` instead. `var_dump()` only displays (dumps) the contents of a `variable`. It is mainly used for debugging... An update has been made to this Post to reflect this... ;-)